# can't get rid of right margin

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm making a wall of videos and despite specifying 0 margin and padding in the style it keeos displaying with a right margin. Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
html,body{margin:0; padding:0;}
</style>
</head>  
<body>

<iframe width="473" height="353" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PC3o2KgQstA?     modestbranding=0&showinfo=0&controls=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=PC3o2KgQstA"></iframe>
<iframe width="473" height="353" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/f4G68civvo8?modestbranding=0&showinfo=0&controls=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=f4G68civvo8"></iframe>
<iframe width="473" height="353" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8UHupHDwJJQ?modestbranding=0&showinfo=0&controls=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=8UHupHDwJJQ"></iframe>
<iframe width="473" height="353" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/q0S642NtHtE?modestbranding=0&showinfo=0&controls=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=q0S642NtHtE"></iframe>
<iframe width="473" height="353" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MTY1Kje0yLg?modestbranding=0&showinfo=0&controls=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=MTY1Kje0yLg"></iframe>
<iframe width="473" height="353" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8tnDzdQDtLY?modestbranding=0&showinfo=0&controls=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=8tnDzdQDtLY"></iframe>
<iframe width="473" height="353" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ntQ7qGilqZE?modestbranding=0&showinfo=0&controls=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=ntQ7qGilqZE"></iframe>
<iframe width="473" height="353" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kxX1MMN1n-Y?modestbranding=0&showinfo=0&controls=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=kxX1MMN1n-Y"></iframe>
<iframe width="473" height="353" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yC8O5HPvfsg?modestbranding=0&showinfo=0&controls=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=yC8O5HPvfsg"></iframe>
<iframe width="473" height="353" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4oQ2wo1YU0o?modestbranding=0&showinfo=0&controls=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=4oQ2wo1YU0o"></iframe>
<iframe width="473" height="353" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uAstltdJkXI?modestbranding=0&showinfo=0&controls=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=uAstltdJkXI"></iframe>
<iframe width="473" height="353" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bqha8360_8M?modestbranding=0&showinfo=0&controls=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=Bqha8360_8M"></iframe>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it runs fine on my machine, stressed tested it for a full 24hours. I just need it to run on one machine for an installation..not supposed to be web safe for general public. Maybe your flash is out of date/conflicting with pepperflash?

Comment: try putting margin:0 for `iframe, iframe *`..

Comment: setting the margin to 0 for iframe didn't work

Comment: So iframes are inline(-block?) elements... To avoid a little gap, you can place the iframes closing and opening tags right next to each other: `<iframe></iframe><iframe>` [like in this example there is no margin, only a little inline gap underneath each iframe](http://jsbin.com/xutala/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: add div class as a parent to all iframe. check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sda64sw2/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/sda64sw2/1/

added `100% width` and `text-align:center`;

```
   html,body{
    margin:0 auto; 
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    }
```